# finding the average of array then finding the number above the average to print

Tags: java, arrays, average

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProjectFour {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
int[] firstArray = {1,2,3,2,1,6,3,4,5};
System.out.println("this is the average of array : "+analyzeNumbers(firstArray));
System.out.println("These are the numbers above the average : "+aboveAvg(firstArray));
    }
    //finding the average
    public static int analyzeNumbers(int[] firstArray){    
    int avg;
    avg=sumArray(firstArray);
    avg=avg/firstArray.length;
    return avg;
    }
    //suming the array method
    public static int sumArray(int[] firstArray){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int x=0;x<firstArray.length;x++){
        sum+=firstArray[x];
    }
    return sum;
}

**this is where im running into problems im kinda stumpted**
```

// this is my method i cant figure out trying to take the average and find all the numbers in the array above the average and printing them.

```
 public static int aboveAvg(int[] firstArray){
    int[] aboveAvg;
    aboveAvg = new int[0];
    int x;
    for(x=analyzeNumbers(firstArray);x<firstArray.length;x++){
        aboveAvg+=firstArray[x];
    }
    return aboveAvg;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Why not creating a function that will compute the average and then pass it in parameter to your `aboveAvg` method to return only the values above it ? 

And you are setting `aboveAvg = new int[0];` so the size of your array will be 0. Use `aboveAvg = new int[10];` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop.

```
int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < firstArray; i++) {
int getSum = firstArray.get(i);
sum + getSum;
    }
int average = sum / firstArray.length;

int[] aboveAverage;
for(int c = 0; c < firstArray; c++) {
if(firstArray.get(c) > average) {
aboveAverage.add(firstArray.get(c));
}
}
```

Comment: sum + getSum; compiler says its not a statement due to the "+"

Answer (score 0):

This aboveAvg function is completly wrong.

```
public static List<Integer> aboveAvg(int[] firstArray){
    List<Integer> aboveAvg = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int Avg = analyzeNumbers(firstArray);
    for(int i = 0; i<firstArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(firstArray[i] > Avg)
        {
            aboveAvg.add(firstArray[i]);
        } 
    }
    return aboveAvg;
}
```

- Check your for loop and more examples about it
- += will sum two values, won't add new element on any array.
- you have to define your return value correctly.
- You can use `List` for create arrays, it's more flexible.